# How to use media queries properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am designing a responsive web page. I have a div whose width should decrease when the screen size decreases.

This div also contains a list of two image links. They should remain inline even when the screen width decrease.

```
/* The CSS */
div.mymenu{
margin-right:7%;
margin-top:-53px;
background:#000;
width: 28.5%;
opacity:0.8;
}

div.mymenu > .nav-pills{
margin-bottom:7px;
}

div.mymenu > .nav-pills a{
color:#fff;
margin-left: 30%;
}

div.mymenu > .nav-pills a:hover{
background:none;
} 

<!-- The HTML -->

<div class="mymenu pull-right">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li><a href="">Why Us</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="img/news.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="img/help.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I am using twitter bootstrap. I tried making changes to bootstrap-responsive.css - but no change. I made changes such as :-

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
.mymenu{
 width: 20%;
}
}
```

Comment: Try to replicate the issue in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or similar to get a better and more useful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current media query is going to limit those styles to browsers between `768px` and `979px`. Remove the 2nd media query (979) to have it apply to all viewports wider than `768 px`.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)  {
    .mymenu {
      width: 20%;
    }
}
```

Also, just a note, i'd suggest trimming selectors like `div.mymenu` down to just `.mymenu` the `div` limits the applicability of the selector (perhaps you will want a `ul` to have the same styles as `.mymenu`) and it's more typing : )

Comment: can I make this change in a new media queries file or shld i include it in bootstrap-responsive.css?

Comment: You can do it in either. Although, for organizational reasons I would suggest using a separate ``mystyles.css`` document, putting your modifications in there, and then using css's ``@import`` [info - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@import) to bring in the bootstrap files. Ideally though, you would combine all your css files together in one minified file with a utility like [codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) or [smoosh](https://github.com/fat/smoosh). Otherwise, it can be difficult to locate your changes amongst the bootstrap code.

Comment: hey, I tried, but no change. The icons are  coming in a separate line and no change in width

Comment: Try changing ``div.mymenu`` to ``.mymenu``. Also, Can you make a [codepen](http://codepen.io/) example?

Answer (score 3):

For fluid designs, I very much recommend using Skeleton: http://www.getskeleton.com/

Here you have a standard for @media queries

```
/* #Tablet (Portrait)
================================================== */
    /* Note: Design for a width of 768px */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {

    }


/*  #Mobile (Portrait)
================================================== */
    /* Note: Design for a width of 320px */

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    }


/* #Mobile (Landscape)
================================================== */
    /* Note: Design for a width of 480px */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

    }
```

Greetings from Argentina!

Answer (score 3):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```